# Ввод данных типа double в двумерный массив через строки string или char

Tags: java, c++, c, массивы

Нужно ввести произвольную строку, содержащую символы, положительные и отрицательные  вещественные числа с клавиатуры. В качестве разделителей в строке нужно использовать пробелы. Затем необходимо сформировать из строки двумерный массив (матрицу) типа double. Код нужен на С, С++ и Java. Вот мой код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
char *locale = setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

string str_a;
gets (str_a.c_str());
cout << "Заполните матрицу А произвольными вещественными числами. В строке должно быть четыре числа. Разделите числа пробелами: \r\n";


string intermediate;
double dnumA;
vector <double> vecA;

for (int i = 0; i < str_a.length(); i++) {
    if (str_a [i] != ' ') {
        intermediate += str_a [i];
    }
        else {
            dnumA = atof (intermediate.c_str());
            intermediate.clear();
            vecA.push_back(dnumA);
            }       
};

            dnumA = atof (intermediate.c_str());
            intermediate.clear();
            vecA.push_back(dnumA);

for (int i = 0; i < vecA.size(); i++) {
    cout << vecA[i] << " " << "\r\n";
}
return 0;
```

В чем ошибки?
Вот скрин с ошибками [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так это ж не матрица, а обычный одномерный массив. что б матрица была надо как минимум так вектор создать: vector<vector<double>>

Comment: Да, это так. Но хотелось бы хотя бы с вектором сначала разобраться. Я думаю сделать матрицу через вложенные вектора, но даже с одним вектором не работает пока.

Comment: меня смущает у вас -"содержащую символы". это значит, что могут быть не только числа, но еще и буквы?

Comment: Да, буквы тоже должны быть.

Comment: весь cout пишем в одну строку, без перевода на следующую. ошибка исчезнет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через вложенный вот так работать будет:

```
vector<vector<double>> arr;
vector<double> vec1{1,2,3};
vector<double> vec2{4,5,6};
arr.push_back(vec1);
arr.push_back(vec2);

for(auto a:arr){
    for(auto v:a){
        cout<<v<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

это я привел пример как создать двумерный

подправил ваш пример, теперь запускается и работает. но с одномерным

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
char *locale = setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

string str_a;
getline(cin, str_a);
cout << "Заполните матрицу А произвольными вещественными числами. В строке должно быть четыре числа. Разделите числа пробелами: \r\n";


string intermediate;
double dnumA;
vector <double> vecA;

for (int i = 0; i < str_a.length(); i++) {
    if (str_a [i] != ' ') {
        intermediate += str_a [i];
    }
        else {
            dnumA = atof (intermediate.c_str());
            intermediate.clear();
            vecA.push_back(dnumA);
           }
};

            dnumA = atof (intermediate.c_str());
            intermediate.clear();
            vecA.push_back(dnumA);

for (int i = 0; i < vecA.size(); i++) {
    cout << vecA[i] << " " << "\r\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

от букв в строке можно вот так избавится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема не в создании матрицы, а в том, что даже с  одномерным массивом код не компилируется. .

Comment: я же говорю, что исправил. теперь компилится

Comment: У меня все еще выдает ошибки. Как прикрепить скриншот не знаю, новичок здесь. Смущает ошибка missing terminating " character

Comment: вы скопировали мой код и у вас такая ошибка? картинку в коментах никак не вставить, можете в свой вопрос ее вставить. там при редактировании есть панель, на этой панели есть кнопка вставки картинки

Comment: кажется догадывась где у вас ошибка. здесь? "cout << "Заполните матрицу А произвольными вещественными числами. В строке 
должно быть четыре числа. Разделите числа пробелами: \r\n";" Если да, то просто напишите это в одну строку, компилятор не может понять что это за символы

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. А шестистрочную матрицу чтобы сделать, выходит нужно сделать шесть аналогичных векторов и записать их в один?

Comment: да, именно так. я вам сверху приводил пример как на две строки сделать, на шесть по аналогии полностью

Answer (score 0):

Наверное вам нужно что то вроде этого:

```
string s;
vector <string > intermediate;
while (cin >> s)
    intermediate.push_back(s);
size_t sz = intermediate.size();
vector< vector<double> > res(sz);
for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    s = intermediate[i];
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(res[i]));
}
for (const auto& v : res) {
    for (double d : v)
        cout << d << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```